# pandas merge produce duplicate columns

Tags: pandas, merge, duplicates

```
n1 = DataFrame({'zhanghui':[1,2,3,4] , 'wudi':[17,'gx',356,23] ,'sas'[234,51,354,123]  })
n2 = DataFrame({'zhanghui_x':[1,2,3,5] , 'wudi':[17,23,'sd',23] ,'wudi_x':[17,23,'x356',23] ,'wudi_y':[17,23,'y356',23] ,'ddd':[234,51,354,123]  })
```

code above defined two DataFrame objects. I wanna use 'zhanghui' field from n1 and 'zhanghui_x' field from n2 as "on" field merge n1 and n2,so my code like this:

```
n1.merge(n2,how = 'inner',left_on = 'zhanghui',right_on='zhanghui_x')
```

and then result columns given like this :

```
sas     wudi_x  zhanghui    ddd     wudi_y  wudi_x  wudi_y  zhanghui_x
```

Some duplicate columns appeared,such as 'wudi_x' ,'wudi_y'.
So it's a pandas inner problems or I had a wrong usage about pd.merge ?

Comment: Please post the desired output, this is expected behaviour as you have row values that are not the same so it prepends the clashed values as new x and y columns

Answer (score 1):

From pandas documentation, the merge() function has following properties;

```
pd.merge(left, right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None,
     left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=True,
     suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True, indicator=False,
     validate=None)
```

where **suffixes** denote default suffix string to be attached to 'over-lapping' columns with defaults **'_x'** and **'_y'**.

I'm not sure if I understood your follow-up question correctly, but;

## Case 1

If the first dataFrame has column **'column_name_x'** and the second dataFrame has column **'column_name'** then there are no over-lapping columns and therefore no suffixes are attached.

## Case 2

If the first dataFrame has columns **'column_name'**, **'column_name_x'** and the second dataFrame also has column **'column_name'**, the default suffixes attach to over-lapping columns and therefore the first frame's **'columnn_name'** becomes **'column_name_x'** and result in a duplicate of already existing column.

You can however, pass a **None** value to one(*not all*) of the suffixes to ensure that column names of certain dataFrame remain as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is right, pandas automatically gives postscripts after merging the columns that are "duplicated" with the original headers given a postscript _x, _y, etc.

you can first select what columns to merge and proceed:

```
cols_to_use = n2.columns - n1.columns
n1.merge(n2[cols_to_use],how = 'inner',left_on = 'zhanghui',right_on='zhanghui_x')
```

result columns:

```
sas wudi    zhanghui    ddd wudi_x  wudi_y  zhanghui_x
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run `cols_to_use = n2.columns - n1.columns`,it gave me a TypeError like this:

```
cannot perform __sub__ with this index type: <class pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
```

then I tried to use code below:

```
cols_to_use = [i for i in list(n2.columns) if i not in list(n1.columns) ]
```

It worked fine,result columns given like this:

```
sas  wudi   zhanghui    ddd wudi_x  wudi_y  zhanghui_x
```

So,@S Ringne's method really resolved my problems.

=============================================

Pandas just simply add suffix such as '_x' to resolve the duplicate-column-name problem when it comes to merging two Frame objects.

**But what will it happen if the name form of 'a-column-name'+'_x' appears in either Frame object?** I used to think that it will check if the name form of 'a-column-name'+'_x' appears, But actually pandas doesn't have this check?